# travis " Segmentation fault " but works fine locally

Tags: travis-ci

there, I ran into a 'Segmentation fault' error when using travis-ci for my project : [IPython-Dashboard](https://github.com/litaotao/IPython-Dashboard/tree/v-0.1.5-sql-server-log)

there is no error msg and it works fine on local, I feel a little confusing. any one can give any idea on fixing this, thanks.

---

here is the travis build log on cloud:

[travis-log](https://travis-ci.org/litaotao/IPython-Dashboard/builds/99570869)

```
$ nosetests --with-coverage --cover-package=dashboard

../home/travis/build.sh: line 45:  3187 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) 
nosetests --with-coverage --cover-package=dashboard

The command "nosetests --with-coverage --cover-package=dashboard" exited with 139.
```

---

here is the build log on local [osx]

```
taotao@mac007:~/Desktop/github/IPython-Dashboard$sudo nosetests --with-coverage --cover-package=dashboard
.../Users/chenshan/Desktop/github/IPython-Dashboard/dashboard/tests/testCreateData.py:78: Warning: Can't create database 'IPD_data'; database exists
  conn.cursor().execute('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {};'.format(config.sql_db))
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py:599: FutureWarning: The 'mysql' flavor with DBAPI connection is deprecated and will be removed in future versions. MySQL will be further supported with SQLAlchemy engines.
  warnings.warn(_MYSQL_WARNING, FutureWarning)
...
Name                                    Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
---------------------------------------------------------------------
dashboard.py                               13      0   100%
dashboard/client.py                         1      0   100%
dashboard/client/sender.py                 11      3    73%   26-27, 33
dashboard/conf.py                           0      0   100%
dashboard/conf/config.py                   29      0   100%
dashboard/server.py                         0      0   100%
dashboard/server/resources.py               0      0   100%
dashboard/server/resources/dash.py         35     10    71%   36, 55-56, 67-69, 86-89
dashboard/server/resources/home.py         40     12    70%   25, 28-30, 83-91
dashboard/server/resources/sql.py          27     11    59%   30, 52-75
dashboard/server/resources/status.py        8      1    88%   19
dashboard/server/resources/storage.py      13      5    62%   26-28, 43-47
dashboard/server/utils.py                  79     18    77%   20-24, 78-80, 82-83, 86, 96, 99-100, 126-127, 140-142
dashboard/server/views.py                  21      1    95%   16
---------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                     277     61    78%
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 6 tests in 4.600s

OK
taotao@mac007:~/Desktop/github/IPython-Dashboard$
```

Comment: I'm also confronted to a travis-only segmentation fault (also only with python 2.7), in my case it's linked to `matplotlib` and occurs when running `coverage run --source=nngt src/nngt/testing/__init__.py`.
Error is related to gtk apparently.

Comment: have u ever figured it out?

Comment: noting that osx is supposed to produce segfault backtrack, and there are segfault logging libraries one can link to